# How do I create and if condition for strings in python

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements, statements

Hello I've been trying to get this line of code working but it keeps going down to the else: statement.
Any ideas?

I cant understand what I'm doing wrong for it not to accept the if: condition.

```
print('What do you get when you cross a snowman with a vampire?')
answer1 = input()
if answer1.lower 'frostbite':
    print ('Huh? how did you know that YOU SPY!')

else:
    print('FROSBITE!')
```

Comment: Does your code actually read `answer1.lower == 'frostbite'`?

Comment: @mgilson `answer1.lower()`

Comment: if `answer1.lower() == 'frostbite':`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi -- I doubt that's what OP has.  If it is, OP's code _should_ work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell with the code fragment since it has a `SyntaxError`, but I'm guessing you have:

```
if answer1.lower == 'frostbite':
    ...
```

The problem here is that `answer.lower` is a *bound method* which is clearly not equal to any string.  You need to call it to actually generate the lower case string:

```
if answer1.lower() == 'frostbite':
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me the answer

Thanks friends

```
print('What do you get when you cross a snowman with a vampire?')
answer1 = input()
if answer1.lower() == 'frostbite':
   print ('Huh? how did you know that YOU SPY!')

else:
    print('FROSBITE!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the strings:

```
print('What do you get when you cross a snowman with a vampire?')

answer1 = input()

correct = 'frostbite'

if answer1.lower == correct :
    print ('Huh? how did you know that YOU SPY!')

else:
    print('FROSBITE!')
```

Comment: `lower` is actually a method, so you'd want to call it.